# Overriding file download/view on SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have been asked to develop a new feature for Sharepoint Server 2013 on premise which I have no idea how to implement. It basically consists on "catch" any user attempt to download/open a PDF file on a specific Sharepoint site, add a watermark behind the scene, and deliver the newly edited file to the end user.

I have edited PDF documents programmatically hundreds of times using C# libraries, but I don't know how can I manage to override the default behavior to achieve this requirement.

Can anyone please give me some guidance? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure if you have considered 'Record Centre'.  There are certain features in the Record Centre will meet your requirements.  For example, the user will be forced to enter a label and barcode before saving.  Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Hi, how can the Record Centre be used to achieve my requirements? I have never made use of it before so I would appreciate some hints on it.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Implement-Records-Management-0bfe419e-eb1d-421a-becd-5be9fed1e479

Answer (score 0):

You will possibly need to create a custom webpart to show links to the downloadable documents then handle the events with code behind logic using the c# libraries that you have already used. I dont think you would be able to achieve this just by presenting the document library default view pages to the end users

Comment: Hi @HarryB, thanks for your response. I finally found in the following link what seems to be the solution I was looking for: <http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2012/03/stamping-pdf-files-downloaded-from-sharepoint-2010/#comment-235264>. Even though that solution has several problems: PDF documents opened or downloaded through the Explorer View via WebDAV are not stamped and the HttpHandler is applied to the whole Sharepoint web application, instead of specific site collections.